# To find quadratic equation if roots are fractional numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let roots of a quadratic equation are 1 and 2, then equation would be $$(x – 1)(x – 2) = x^2-3x+2$$
Consider the equation $2x^2+7x+5$. Its roots are $-1$ and $-5/2$. If we multiply these two factors $(x+1)$ and $(x+5/2)$we get $x^2+(7/2) x + (5/2)$. Here, we get coefficient of $x^2$ unity.

My question is, does this method of obtaining quadratic equation by multiplying its factors applicable only when the coefficient of $x^2$ is unity?

Comment: Well, as you can see it youself, when you multiply the factors of the form $(x-x_0)$, you get AN expression that has the roots. Any multiplicative of the expression also has the same roots.

Comment: Yes, I know they have the same roots, but my question is, why I am getting the coefficient of $x^2$ unity?

Comment: Because both coefficients of $x$ in the two linear term are also unity. It’s as simple as that. Knowing the roots does help you factor the expression, but you also have to take the coefficient of $x^2$ into account somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any roots $r$ and $s$, the polynomial

$$a(x-r)(x-s)$$ is zero at $r$ and $s$.

And

$$a(x-r)(x-s)=ax^2-a(r+s)x+ars=ax^2+bx+c.$$

This answers your question.

Comment: You mean $2x^2+7x+5$ = $2(x+1)(x+5/2)$. Does this mean that if in any quadratic equation, coefficient of $x^2$ is not unity (let $n$), and let its two factors are $a$ and $b$, then the original equation would be $n(x-a)(x-b)$?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra: absolutely.

Comment: @Shekar Malhotra, yes indeed. It also extends to polynomials of any degree. Also, since there are infinite values of $n$, there are infinite polynomials of the form $n(x-a)(x-b)$ with roots being $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \ne 0$. Then $ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+ \frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}).$

Furthermore: $ x_0 $ is a solution of  $ax^2+bx+c=0 \iff x_0 $ is a solution of $x^2+ \frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=0.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I understand that the two equations will have the same roots, but my question is why I am not getting the expression $2x^2+7x+5$ by multiplying two factors?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra, because your leading coefficient is $2$. If you want to get $2x^2+7x+5$, you have to multiply $2(x+1)(x+\frac{5}{2})$.

Comment: @Atticus: That is what my question is, does this method of obtaining original quadratic equation, by multiplying its factors, applicable only when the coefficient of $x^2$ is unity? Does this mean that if in any quadratic equation, coefficient of $x^2$ is not unity (let $n$), and let its two factors are $a$ and $b$, then the original equation would be $n(x−a)(x−b)$?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra, Yes. if $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0, a\neq 0$, then $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$

Comment: The roots of a polynomial do not fully identify it: only up to a constant factor.  This is what you are seeing. One way to see this is that a typical degree $n$ polynomial has $n + 1$ coefficients but $n$ roots.  You have lost some information.  Requiring the leading coefficient to be $1$ is one way to deal with this.